# how to sort this array php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having the following array and I would like to order theme after the prices value. I have been checking in the php manual the array_multisort() function but it's not really clear how could I achieve results.

my array looks

```
array=>(0=>array(id=>'1', name=>'example1', price='200'))
array=>(1=>array(id=>'2', name=>'example1', price='120'))
array=>(2=>array(id=>'3', name=>'example1', price='160'))
```

after the price value the order should be

```
array=>(1=>array(id=>'2', name=>'example1', price='120'))
array=>(2=>array(id=>'3', name=>'example1', price='160'))
array=>(0=>array(id=>'1', name=>'example1', price='200'))
```

Comment: SO needs to recognize `Sort` and `Array` in the question and automatically link to http://php.net/usort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
    if ($a ['price'] == $b ['price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a ['price'] < $b ['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort ($array, "cmp");
```

MonkeyMonkeys' alternative:

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
    return ($a ['price'] - $b ['price']);
}

usort ($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: Instead of comparing, you can use this `return $a['price'] - $b['price']`

Comment: thanks for your response! The problem is, that I would like to implement this reordering in my view and as I understood is not a good practice to call functions in such a cases. This would be the only solution?

Comment: That's simply not true, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: okay I have been using this function in my controller earlier so I have it, how can I refer to from view to get the desired result?

Comment: How can I possible know, I don't know what your PHP setup is... just use this code, you can paste the function within your controller function.